# Add a method to Card that creates a full deck of cards, with one card of each combination of rank and suit

Tags: swift, swift-playground

So I have been doing the experiments that are in the Apple Swift Book.

I have been able to do all of them, except for this one so far. Below is what I have tried, but I can't figure out how to get it working.

> Add a method to *Card* that creates a full deck of cards, with one card of each combination of rank and suit.

```
// Playground - noun: a place where people can play

enum Rank: Int {
    case Ace = 1
    case Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten
    case Jack, Queen, King

    func simpleDescription() -> String {
        switch self {
            case .Ace:
                return "ace"
            case .Jack:
                return "jack"
            case .Queen:
                return "queen"
            case .King:
                return "king"
            default:
                return String(self.toRaw())
        }
    }
}

enum Suit {
    case Spades, Hearts, Diamonds, Clubs

    func simpleDescription() -> String {
        switch self {
            case .Spades:
                return "spades"
            case .Hearts:
                return "hearts"
            case .Diamonds:
                return "diamonds"
            case .Clubs:
                return "clubs"
        }
    }
}

struct Card {
    var rank: Rank
    var suit: Suit

    func simpleDescription() -> String {
        return "The \(rank.simpleDescription()) of \(suit.simpleDescription())"
    }

    func createFullDeck() -> Array{
        var FullDeck: Array

        FullDeck = Card(rank: .Ace, suit: .Spades)
        FullDeck = Card(rank: .Two, suit: .Spades)

        return FullDeck
    }
}

let threeOfSpades = Card(rank: .Three, suit: .Spades)
let threeOfSpadesDescription = threeOfSpades.simpleDescription()

threeOfSpades.createFullDeck()
```

- I don't know what I am supposed to return for that method, an Array?
- Should I use a for loop to create this? or is there a proper/easier way to do this with enum
- Why would I create this method inside of *Card*, calling `threeOfSpades.createFullDeck()` seems incorrect.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's another way of doing it, this time only using techniques you would have learned up to that point*

First we define the possible ranks and suits, using the respective `Rank` and `Suit` enums defined previously.

Next we have the function iterate over each rank within each suit, creating a card for each, and finally returning an array of the cards.

```
struct Card {
    var rank: Rank
    var suit: Suit
    func simpleDescription() -> String {
        return "The \(rank.simpleDescription()) of \(suit.simpleDescription())"
    }

    func createDeck() -> [Card] {
        let ranks = [Rank.ace, Rank.two, Rank.three, Rank.four, Rank.five, Rank.six, Rank.seven, Rank.eight, Rank.nine, Rank.ten, Rank.jack, Rank.queen, Rank.king]
        let suits = [Suit.spades, Suit.hearts, Suit.diamonds, Suit.clubs]
        var deck = [Card]()
        for suit in suits {
            for rank in ranks {
                deck.append(Card(rank: rank, suit: suit))
            }
        }
        return deck
    }
}
```

(* with the notable exception that the tour hadn't explicitly explained how to append to arrays at that point)

Comment: you can also use `+=` to append to an array (first mention circa p.20 in "Generics")

Comment: only when appending another array

Comment: For more generalized approaches to enumerating possible values of an enum, Nate Cook explores some more advanced techniques here: http://natecook.com/blog/2014/10/loopy-random-enum-ideas/. Of course, these wouldn't have been covered in the Swift Tutorial at this early a point in the book.

Comment: Should it not be `func createDeck() -> [Card]` instead of `func createDeck() -> Card[]`.
Notice the syntax of array of `Card`

Comment: When you make `createDeck` a `static func` and call it with `Card.createDeck()` you just get [{(enum value), (enum value)}] 52 times.  How do you call it and get the actual String back?

Comment: This is old but here is a version running the IBM Swift Sandbox (made function static): http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/6b968d70e21d0791c008d4eb12aab3a1a39bf74390f799705b73651927ae23ed

Answer (score 9):

A robust code answer will not to the use actual values (i.e., .Spades) from the enumerations when generating the deck, e.g., if a "Joker" is added later to the Rank enumeration (anywhere in the enumeration), the deck generation function should still work without change.

The design questions (what to return?, should the deck generation be a function of card?) are not really relevant to this tutorial, but it is likely that a Deck class would be preferable if any serious functionality is going to be built out further (e.g., shuffle).  So for now, returning an Array from a function in the Card structure is all that is required.

The following code (as far as possible only using what has been described up to this point in the tutorial) defines a function in the Card Structure that loops through the Suit and Rank enumerations without needing to know any of the enumeration values and returns an Array:

```
static func deck() -> [Card] {
    var deck = [Card]()
    var suitCount = 1
    while let suit = Suit(rawValue: suitCount) {
        var rankCount = 1
        while let rank = Rank(rawValue: rankCount) {
            deck.append(Card(rank: rank, suit: suit))
            rankCount += 1
        }
        suitCount += 1
    }
    return deck
}
```

Invoke this with:

```
let deck = Card.deck()
var card3 = deck[3].simpleDescription()
```

Copy the function into the Card structure and try adding values to enums.  Note the following:

- how the number of times the loops are executed changes when adding to the enums
- that both enum counters start at 1 (if not otherwise specified in the enumeration the first raw value is one)
- unspecified array indexes start at 0 (e.g., deck[3] is actually the 4 of Spades)

Comment: I like the idea of lowering coupling. But simply adding a `Joker` to the enumeration wont work out of the box - as it will create 4 jokers, one of each suit. Jokers don't have a suit, so either way, you have to design special cases for jokers.

Comment: In the playground, the `enum Suit` doesn't have a raw value. For this solution to work, the enum has to changed to use one:
    `enum Suit: Int {`

Answer (score 4):

The experiment asks for a method to Card. So I I declared the method as being static so that it acts on the struct and not an instance of it:

```
struct Card {
    var rank: Rank
    var suit: Suit

    func simpleDescription() -> String {
        return "The \(rank.simpleDescription()) of \(suit.simpleDescription())"
    }

    static func deck() -> [Card] {
        var deck: [Card] = []
        for suit in [Suit.Spades, Suit.Hearts, Suit.Diamonds, Suit.Clubs] {
            for rank in 0...13 {
                if let unwrappedRank = Rank.fromRaw(rank) {
                    deck.append(Card(rank: unwrappedRank, suit: suit))
                }
            }
        }
        return deck
    }
}
```

To make use of it:

```
let deck = Card.deck()
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: rank from 0...13 would be 14 steps, you need only 13

Comment: Correct, The conditional  ***if let unwrappedRank = Rank.fromRaw(rank)*** returns a nil for 0 therefore the deck in not appended. ***unwrappedRank*** is an optional since the init?(rawValue:) initializer is optional.

Comment: Xcode now requires `Rank.fromRaw(rank)` to be written as `Rank(rawValue: rank)`

Answer (score 3):

By conforming to `CaseIterable` **protocol**, you will get the `allCases` computed property for free:

```
extension Rank: CaseIterable { }
extension Suit: CaseIterable { }
```

then you can use `map`s to achieve it all at once:

```
func createDeck() -> [Card] {
    Suit.allCases.flatMap{ s in Rank.allCases.map{ r in Card(rank: r, suit: s) }}
}
```

`flatMap` was used to convert nested arrays into a 1-dimensional (flat) array.

Answer (score 1):

A for loop is the way to go. I made a few adjustments in your base code. First, I added a type to your Suit enum.

```
enum Suit : Int
```

Then I added a class called Deck which is responsible for a deck of cards.

```
class Deck {
    var cards:Card[]

    init() {
        self.cards = Array<Card>()
    }

    func createDeck() {
        for suit in 0...Suit.Clubs.toRaw() {
            for rank in 1...Rank.King.toRaw() {
                self.cards += Card(rank: Rank.fromRaw(rank)!, suit: Suit.fromRaw(suit)!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`func createDeck()` loops through all possible playing cards and adds them to your deck.

Comment: Yes, this make sense... I wonder why Apple would say "Experiment: Add a method to _Card_ that creates a full deck of cards, with one card of each combination of rank and suit." It seems like a class would be a better option.

Comment: @downvoter Could you please explain your decision so that I may make my answer better.

Comment: I'm not the down voter, but you can no longer add elements using `+=` you must use the `.append()` method or use array concatenation (i.e., `+= [element]`), which the `+=` operator still supports. PS - my answer was mysteriously down voted as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the whole solution for Swift 3:

```
struct Card {

    var rank: Rank
    var suit: Suit

    func simpleDescription() -> String {
        return "The \(rank.simpleDescription()) of \(suit.simpleDescription())"
    }
    func createDeck() -> [Card] {
        let suits = [Suit.spades, Suit.hearts, Suit.clubs, Suit.diamonds]
        var deck = [Card]()

        for theSuit in suits {
            for theRank in Rank.Ace.rawValue...Rank.King.rawValue {
                deck.append(Card(rank: Rank(rawValue: theRank)!, suit: theSuit))
            }
        }
        return deck
    }
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
let aceOfHearts = Card(rank: .Ace, suit: .hearts)
let deck = aceOfHearts.createDeck()
```

Answer (score 1):

I left everything like in Swift Tour, Suit is String and  Rank is Int.

```
struct Card {
    var rank: Rank
    var suit: Suit

    func simpleDescription () -> String{
        return "The \(rank.simpleDescription()) of \suit.simpleDescription())"
}

    func createDeck() -> [Card] {
        var n = 1
        var deck = [Card]()
        let suits = [Suit.spades, Suit.hearts, Suit.diamonds, Suit.clubs]
        while let rank = Rank(rawValue: n) {
            for suit in suits {
                deck.append(Card(rank: rank, suit: suit))
            }
            n += 1
        }
        return deck
    }
}   
let card = Card (rank: Rank.ace, suit: Suit.spades)
let deck = card.createDeck()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip two build all cases at once!

## First:

conforming to `CaseIterable` **protocol**:

```
extension Rank: CaseIterable { }
extension Suit: CaseIterable { }
```

So you will get the `allCases` computed property for free:

> Suit.allCases
>
> Rank.allCases

## Second:

then you can use `map`s to achieve all at once:

```
func createDeck() -> [Card] {
    zip(Rank.allCases, Suit.allCases).map { Card(rank: $0.0, suit: $0.1) }
}
```

The `zip` will build the need and the `map` will convert all to `Card`s

Answer (score 1):

```
static func deck() -> [Card] {
    var deck = [Card]()
    for rankRawValue in Rank.ace.rawValue...Rank.king.rawValue {
        deck.append(Card(rank: Rank(rawValue: rankRawValue)!, suit: Suit.spades))
        deck.append(Card(rank: Rank(rawValue: rankRawValue)!, suit: Suit.hearts))
        deck.append(Card(rank: Rank(rawValue: rankRawValue)!, suit: Suit.diamonds))
        deck.append(Card(rank: Rank(rawValue: rankRawValue)!, suit: Suit.clubs))
    }
    return deck
}
```

More than one great answers already offered, I like the CaseIterable solution.  But here's just another variation that seems to work, peer review would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First I'll tackle the easiest question: Where you put the code that creates the full deck is up to you, but I would advise you *not* to put it in `Card`, but rather create a `Deck` class and provide a [**convenience initializer**](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_284) to do it there.

That said, let's continue with the plan of adding it to the `Card` class. Unfortunately there is no way to just loop over all possible values of an Enum in the way you'd hope (though I'd love to be wrong about this!), but you *can* do this:

```
let first_card = Rank.Ace.toRaw() // == 1
let last_card = Rank.King.toRaw() // == 13

for raw_rank in first_card...last_card {
    let rank = Rank.fromRaw(raw_rank)!
}
```

Let's walk through this. An Enum assigns an underlying value to each case, and by writing `case Ace = 1` you're setting it up to start counting from 1 (rather than 0, the default). The API provided by an Enum for accessing the underlying value is a `toRaw()` method on each Enum case (The Enum itself also provides it in the form of `Rank.toRaw(Rank.Ace)`.

You can convert back from the raw value using the aptly named `fromRaw()` method (so `Rank.fromRaw(1)` would give us Ace) but there is a caveat: It returns an optional. The return type is `Rank?`, ***not*** `Rank`. In order to access the value you need to [either check for nil, or force unwrap it](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_428).

Checking for nil:

```
if let rank = Rank.fromRaw(1) {
    // Do stuff with rank, which is now a plain old Rank
}
else {
    // handle nil
}
```

Force unwrap:

```
var rank: Rank = Rank.fromRaw(1)!
```

So to answer your question about the loops: Yes, that's the way to do it =P, and yes again about the array, though that's a design decision. It makes just as much sense to create a `Deck` class and return that instead.

Let's add the method using [an extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH24-XID_191). Extensions let you add functionality to an existing type. You can create an extension on a class, enum, or even a primitive type. pretty much anything.

```
extension Card {

    func createFullDeck() -> Card[] {
        var deck: Array<Card> = []
        for raw_rank in Rank.Ace.toRaw()...Rank.King.toRaw() {
            deck += [
                Card(rank:Rank.fromRaw(raw_rank)!, suit:.Spades),
                Card(rank:Rank.fromRaw(raw_rank)!, suit:.Hearts),
                Card(rank:Rank.fromRaw(raw_rank)!, suit:.Diamonds),
                Card(rank:Rank.fromRaw(raw_rank)!, suit:.Clubs),
            ]
        }
        return deck
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, this make sense... I wonder why Apple would say "Experiment: Add a method to _Card_ that creates a full deck of cards, with one card of each combination of rank and suit." It seems like a class would be a better option.

Comment: @Arian I agree, I think they're just trying to teach one thing at a time. Beginners are very sensitive to examples that begin with a wall of code

Comment: Even if you weren't going to create a Deck type, the createFullDeck method should be static. They probably don't because they haven't introduced static methods at this point, but it makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I read the answers above, but then I couldn't use the method ... unless it is a class method.
So I added "static" before the 2 methods I added, and here is my proposal:

```
struct Card {
  var rank: Rank
  var suit: Suit

  func simpleDescription() -> String {
    return "The \(rank.simpleDescription()) of \(suit.simpleDescription())"
  }

  static func createDeck() -> Card[] {
    var deck = Card[]()
    for suit in [Suit.Spades, Suit.Clubs, Suit.Hearts, Suit.Diamonds] {
        for rankRawValue in 1...13 {
            let rank = Rank.fromRaw(rankRawValue)
            let card = Card(rank: rank!, suit: suit)
            deck += card
        }
    }
    return deck
  }

  static func printDeck(deck:Card[]) {
    for card in deck {
        println(card.simpleDescription())
    }
  }
}

let threeOfSpades = Card(rank: .Three, suit: .Spades)
let threeOfSpadesDescription = threeOfSpades.simpleDescription()

let deck = Card.createDeck()
Card.printDeck(deck)
```

But I agree, a "Deck" class would be a better option ...

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, no one has yet had a stab at a functional implementation. Here goes:

```
extension Array {
  func flatten<T>() -> T[] {
    let xs = (self as Any) as Array<Array<T>>
    return xs.reduce(T[]()) { (x, acc) in x + acc }
  }
}

extension Card {
  static func fullDeck() -> Card[] {
    let rawRanks = Array(Rank.Ace.toRaw()...Rank.King.toRaw())
    let suits: Suit[] = [.Spades, .Hearts, .Diamonds, .Clubs]
    return (rawRanks.map {
      rawRank in suits.map {
        suit in Card(rank: Rank.fromRaw(rawRank)!, suit: suit)
        }
      }).flatten()
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a version for swift 3?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to avoid knowledge of the enum definition... It seems clumsy (I'm a beginner), and still needs the starting index: 0 for Suit, 1 for Rank.

```
struct Card {
    var rank: Rank
    var suit: Suit
    func simpleDescription() -> String {
        return "The \(rank.simpleDescription()) of \(suit.simpleDescription())"
    }
    static func deck() -> [Card] {
        var deck = [Card]()
        var suitCount = 0
        while (Suit(rawValue: suitCount) != nil) {
            var rankCount = 1
            while (Rank(rawValue: rankCount) != nil) {
                deck.append(Card(rank: Rank(rawValue: rankCount)!, suit: Suit(rawValue: suitCount)!))
                rankCount++
            }
            suitCount++
        }
        return deck
    }
}
let deck = Card.deck()
```

Answer (score 0):

I just started learning Swift also, and had this same problem. I too thought it was rather odd that the experiment was to create a method inside the Card structure to create a full deck of cards.

After looking at these answers, and reading the official Apple "The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.1)" tour, I solved it like this:

```
struct Card {
    var rank: Rank
    var suit: Suit

    func simpleDescription() -> String {
        return "The \(rank.simpleDescription()) of \(suit.simpleDescription())"
    }

    func createDeck() -> [Card] {
        let suits = [Suit.Spades, Suit.Hearts, Suit.Clubs, Suit.Diamonds]
        var deck = [Card]()

        for theSuit in suits {
            for theRank in Rank.Ace.rawValue...Rank.King.rawValue {
                deck.append(Card(rank: Rank(rawValue: theRank)!, suit: theSuit))
            }
        }

        return deck
    }
}

let aceOfHearts = Card(rank: .Ace, suit: .Hearts)
let deck = aceOfHearts.createDeck()

for card in deck {
    print("\(card.rank) of \(card.suit)")
}
```

Comment: I like this solution. My only light concern is that your implementation know details about the `Rank` implementation. But maybe it's still OK.

Answer (score 0):

Since all the examples above are imperative in nature and Swift is built with functional programming in mind, I took a more functional approach to solving the problem. Here's my full set of code:

My Rank enum (have to define an array with all the values because it's not possible to iterate over all the values of an enum for some reason)

```
enum Rank: Int, CustomStringConvertible {

    case ace = 1
    case two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten
    case jack, queen, king

    static let allRanks = [ace, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, jack, queen, king]

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .ace:
            return "ace"
        case .jack:
            return "jack"
        case .queen:
            return "queen"
        case .king:
            return "king"
        default:
            return String(self.rawValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Suit enum (added similar type of array)

```
enum Suit: String, CustomStringConvertible  {

    case spades = "♠︎"
    case hearts = "♥︎"
    case diamonds = "♦︎"
    case clubs = "♣︎"

    static let allSuits = [spades, hearts, diamonds, clubs]

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        default:
            return rawValue
        }
    }

}
```

...and finally the card:

```
struct Card: CustomStringConvertible {
    var rank: Rank
    var suit: Suit

    var description: String {
        return "\(rank)\(suit)"
    }

    static func createDeckOfCards() -> [Card] {
        return Suit.allSuits.reduce([]) {
            deck, suit in deck + Rank.allRanks.reduce([]) {
                cardsInSuit, rank in cardsInSuit + [Card(rank: rank, suit: suit)]
            }
        }
    }
}

print(Card.createDeckOfCards())
```

Answer (score 0):

As an iOS dev I try to read this book/tutorial about once a year. This year, I thought I'd approach it as a novice developer, and see what I could do based on what information the tutorial had given up to this point. As https://stackoverflow.com/users/262455/jack-james noted they may not have taught .append yet. With that in mind, here is my answer

```
func fullDeck() -> [String] {
    var deckOfCards = [String]()
    let suits = [Suit.clubs, Suit.diamonds, Suit.hearts, Suit.spades]
    let ranks = [Rank.ace, Rank.two, Rank.three, Rank.four, Rank.five, Rank.six, Rank.seven, Rank.eight, Rank.nine, Rank.ten ,Rank.jack, Rank.queen, Rank.king]
    for suit in suits {
        for rank in ranks {
            let card = Card(rank: rank, suit: suit)
            deckOfCards.append(card.simpleDescription())
        }
    }
    print(deckOfCards)
    return deckOfCards
}
```

I agree with the guy above, a class would make more sense, because in this example you need to initialize a Card first in order to call this function...

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Card {
 let suit: Suit
 let rank: Rank

static func simpleDescription(suit: Suit, rank: Rank) -> String {
    let card = Card(suit: suit, rank: rank)
    return "The \(card.rank.simpleDescription) of \(card.suit.simpleDescription)"
}

static func createFullDeck() -> [Card]{
    var fullDeck = [Card]()
    let ranks = Range(2...14)
    let suits = Range(0...3)

    ranks.map { (rank) in
        suits.map { (suit) in
            let card = Card(suit: Suit(rawValue: suit)!, rank: Rank(rawValue: rank)!)
            fullDeck.append(card)
        }
    }
    return fullDeck
 }
}
```

Use case

```
print(Card.simpleDescription(suit: .club, rank: .ace))
```

results = The ace of Club

```
Card.createFullDeck().map { (card) in
print(card.suit, card.rank)
}
```

result prints all value of cards deck.

Answer (score 0):

Array's `map` method allows to call a closure on every array element.
Using effective Swift syntax we can replace explicit `for` loops with just a `map` call:

```
func createDeck() -> [Card] {
        [Suit.spades, Suit.hearts, Suit.diamonds, Suit.clubs].flatMap { suit in
            Array(1...13).map { Card(rank: Rank(rawValue: $0)!, suit: suit) }
        }
    }
```

`flatMap` was used to convert nested arrays to a 1-dimensional (flat) array.

`$0` is a shorthand Swift syntax to access closure params by their number. This allows to skip argument name and `in` keyword in the inner closure.

Comment: Be sure to explain your code so others can understand it.

Comment: Added some explanation