# Stuck on a DeckOfCards class

Tags: swift

I'm working on a poker app. I have 2 questions,,,

1) Just started working on a DeckOfCards class to deal with the deck. I keep getting an error ("Expected Declaration") on one of the for loops. It worked on playgrounds but not in the project (not as a class though). How do I fix this?

2) Is it ok to have the cards represented this way (2 character strings in an array)?

import Foundation

```
class DeckOfCards {

    var newDeck =  ["A♠️", "2♠️", "3♠️", "4♠️", "5♠️",...."K♠️",
                    "A♥️", "2♥️", "3♥️", "4♥️", "5♥️",...."K♥️",
                    "A♣️", "2♣️", "3♣️", "4♣️", "5♣️",...."K♣️",
                    "A♦️", "2♦️", "3♦️", "4♦️", "5♦️",...."K♦️"]

    var deck = [String]()
    var randomNumber = 0

    init() {
        deck = []
    }


    for _ in 1...52 {    // ERROR ON THIS LINE ("Expected Declaration")
        randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(newDeck.count)))
        deck.append(newDeck.removeAtIndex(randomNumber))
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you simply cannot have code hang like this within a class definition. You need to put it in a `func`. e.g.

```
func shuffleDeck() -> [String] {
    var deck = [String]()
    for _ in 1...52 {    
        randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(newDeck.count)))
        deck.append(newDeck.removeAtIndex(randomNumber))
    }
    return deck
}
```

To answer your second part of the question, you are better off to use `enum` to represent the cards. Here is a good example: [Add a method to Card that creates a full deck of cards, with one card of each combination of rank and suit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109691/add-a-method-to-card-that-creates-a-full-deck-of-cards-with-one-card-of-each-co)

Comment: Didn't realise this error at all. I was treating the class as if it was one big func! I have a lot more to learn, lol. Thank you!!

Comment: No worries. Making mistake is always a part of learning a new language. Cheers