# Making a playing card in objective C using enums?

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums

I am trying to make a playing card class in objective c but having some trouble. I am having a lot of trouble converting the enums to strings.

Here is my code:

```
#import "Card.h"

@interface Card()
-(NSString *) convertRankToString:(Rank)rank;
-(NSString *)convertSuitToString:(Suit) suit;
@end

@implementation Card

-(id) initWithSuitAndRank:(Rank)rank suit:(Suit)suit {
   self = [super init];

    if (self) {

        _suit = &suit;
        _rank = &rank;

    }

    return self;
}

-(NSString *) getRank {
    return [self convertRankToString: _rank];
}

-(NSString *) getSuit {
    return [self convertSuitToString: _suit];
}

-(NSString *) getContents {
     return [[self getRank] stringByAppendingString:[self getSuit]];
}

-(NSString *) convertRankToString:(Rank)rank {
switch (rank) {
    case NONE:
        return @"None";
        break;
    case ACE:
        return @"A";
        break;
    case TWO:
        return @"2";
        break;
    case THREE:
        return @"3";
        break;
    case FOUR:
        return @"4";
        break;
    case FIVE:
        return @"5";
        break;
    case SIX:
        return @"6";
        break;
    case SEVEN:
        return @"7";
        break;
    case EIGHT:
        return @"8";
        break;
    case NINE:
        return @"9";
        break;
    case TEN:
        return @"10";
        break;
    case JACK:
        return @"J";
        break;
    case QUEEN:
        return @"Q";
        break;
    case KING:
        return @"K";
        break;
    default:
        return @"";
}
}

-(NSString *)convertSuitToString:(Suit) suit {
    switch (suit) {
        case Clubs:
            return @"♣︎";
            break;
        case Diamonds:
            return @"♦︎";
            break;
        case Hearts:
            return @"♥︎";
            break;
        case Spades:
            return @"♠︎";
            break;
        default:
            return @"";
            break;
    }
}

@end
```

Then I try to fill a deck and call getContents on each card, but all of them are null.

My enums are simply:

```
typedef enum Suit
{
   Clubs,
   Hearts,
   Diamonds,
   Spades
} Suit;
```

And a similar one for rank. Any help is much appreciated.

edit: I currently have warnings saying I cannot pass in _rank or _suit to convertRankToString or convertSuitToString in getContents.

Comment: `_suit = &suit;` is not what you want.  Did you declare your properties as `Suit *` in your .h? It should just be declared as `Suit` like you have in your methods and set with `_suit = suit`.  Same thing with your `rank`

Comment: Yeah i declared Suit *. Let me see if that fixes it

Comment: @dan: awesome it works. thank you so much. if you don't mind can you explain why I wanted Suit and not Suit *? I thought everything in Obj C was pointer based

Comment: Only objects are pointer based.  ObjC uses C-style enums which are not objects, they are like `NSInteger`, `CGFloat`, etc which are primitive values and not objects

Comment: If you search for the warning you're getting you should find some explanation.

Comment: Your `convertSuitToString:` and `convertRankToString:` methods shouldn't take an argument.  They should use the instance variable directly (or use a getter method).

Comment: And you seem to be following an outdated tutorial. There is no reason to declare the private methods in a class extension. And get rid of all of the `break;` statements that immediately follow `return` statements. The `break` statement won't ever be reached.

Comment: Also, the getter methods should not be prefixed with `get`.

Comment: @bbum While true, be careful here. Otherwise `getRank` will get renamed `rank` and will conflict with the getter for the `rank` property (assuming there is a property and not just a `_rank` ivar).

Comment: @maddy Yeah-- true.   Should be something like `rankForDisplay` or `rankString`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here one way to do it

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, Suit) {
    Clubs,
    Hearts,
    Diamonds,
    Spades
};

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, Rank) {
    King,
    Queen,
    Jack,
    // ...
    Three,
    Two,
    One
};

@interface Card : NSObject

    @property (nonatomic, assign) Suit suit;
    @property (nonatomic, assign) Rank rank;

@end


@implementation Card

- (NSString *)stringForSuit
{
    static NSDictionary *SuitToString = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        SuitToString = @{
                         @(Clubs): @"♣︎",
                         @(Hearts): @"♥︎",
                         @(Diamonds): @"♦︎",
                         @(Spades): @"♠︎",
                         };
    });
    return SuitToString[@(self.suit)];
}

- (NSString *)stringForRank
{
    static NSDictionary *RanksToString = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        RanksToString = @{
                          @(King): @"King",
                          @(Queen): @"Queen",
                          @(Jack): @"Jack",
                          // ...
                          @(Three): @"3",
                          @(Two): @"2",
                          @(One): @"Ace",
                          };
    });
    return RanksToString[@(self.rank)];
}

- (NSString *)description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[self stringForRank],[self stringForSuit]];
}

@end
```

Advantages of using `NS_ENUM` [explained on NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/ns_enum-ns_options/) (mainly, better compiler help)

Although, this would all be fun to write in Swift too... (see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109691/add-a-method-to-card-that-creates-a-full-deck-of-cards-with-one-card-of-each-com) for example...)

**Edit**

Other advantage of using ´NS_ENUM´, it generates real Swift enums on the swift side
([source](http://flip.it/S8CQ3))