# iPhone Card Game Deck Generator

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I am trying to program an iPhone App that will create a card set of 10 cards.

The total deck includes about 100 cards with different properties:
Each card has a name, a suit and a cost. 
For an example:

```
card.name = "Test"
card.cost = 2
card.suit = "BasicSet"
```

Let's suppose there are 4 "Sets"* with 20 cards each.
I want the user to be able to select the suit themselves, because most of the suits come from extension sets.

To make it more balanced, I will also decide a maximum and minimum amount of cards with a specific cost (the cost ranging from 2 - 6).

In the end, there will be 2 functions. One function that selects all valid cards (from the available card suits) and another that picks 10 cards at random (taking into account the cost).

**What is the easiest way to implement the cards?** Defining the class `card` and implementing the 100 cards? Or creating 3 arrays with name, cost and origin where one card has the same index in all 3 arrays?

Help would be appreciated?

EDIT:
Each Suit contains unique cards. So if my suits are diamond, spade and so on, there will only be a diamond king, but no spade king. 
Just an example how it could look like:

> Suit Basic {
>   name=Village, cost=2
>   name=City, cost=3
>   name=NewYork, cost=6
>   }
>
> Suit Advanced {
>   name=Tree, cost=4
>   name=Forest, cost=5
>   }
>
> Suit Special {
>   name=Cocktail, cost=2
>   name=OrangeJuice, cost=4
>   }

Comment: Here is a Card implementation using a struct http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109691/add-a-method-to-card-that-creates-a-full-deck-of-cards-with-one-card-of-each-co

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem is: there are 100 cards with 100 names so using `struct` and `for-loops` to create the cards will take a hell lot of time. See the edit

Comment: What about storing the cards as JSON? http://stackoverflow.com/a/26777229/6469239

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One class `Card` could store all necessary information and functions for basic operations. When `Card` class is ready, you could create objects of that class with your data parsed from `plist` or any other format. It's not really necessary to hardcode your data inside the app.

Comment: This is the way to go, try to have as little data hardcoded as possible. Use a medium purpose built for storage instead. Examples are `plist` as above, `XML` or `JSON`. You could then easily update this data with over-the-air updates to tweak gameplay or unlock new cards.