# How to sort an array both numerically and alphabetically in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

Say I have an array:

`var array = ["5C", "4D", "2H", "13S", "4C", "5H"]`

How would I be able to sort this array so that the new array would have the last character sorted alphabetically, then the previous numerical values sorted numerically such as:

`["4C", "5C", "4D", "2H", "5H", "13S"]`

I am relatively new to coding in general and have a very basic grasp of syntax. Other searches have shown me how to sort numerically using the .sorted function and .ascendingOrder, but I couldn't find a solution that could sort both alphabetically and numerically.

Answer (score 3):

You have to write your own comparator which is pretty handy in Swift.

If the last character is the same sort the string without the last character numerically otherwise sort by the last character

```
let array = ["5C", "4D", "2H", "13S", "4C", "5H"]

let sortedArray = array.sorted { (str1, str2) -> Bool in
    if str1.suffix(1) == str2.suffix(1) {
        return str1.dropLast().localizedStandardCompare(str2.dropLast()) == .orderedAscending
    } else {
        return str1.suffix(1) < str2.suffix(1)
    }
}

// ["4C", "5C", "4D", "2H", "5H", "13S"]
```

Comment: You are right, I did not look at the OPs desired results carefully enough. Your answer is correct for the OPs use-case (At least as long as the alpha suffix is always 1 letter, and it needs to be compared in Unicode order. (if the last character is always alpha, and it should be compared case-insensitive then your code will need a little fine-tuning, but your answer returns the desired result for the small data-set.)

Comment: This works! Looking at all the comments I am very grateful for all the answers. And I realize that there is so much left to learn. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

### EDIT:

My answer shows how to use `sorted()` to sort an array of strings into "numeric" order. It is not quite what the OP asked.

To the OP: You should accept vadian's answer. His was the first correct answer.

However, I spend some time in my answer explaining Swift closure syntax, so I am going to leave the answer.

---

You can use the array method `sorted()`, which takes a closure that compares pairs of objects and returns true if the first item should come first.

Then you can use the NSString method `compare(options:)` to do a "numeric" string comparison, where sequences of digits are treated as numbers inside the string.

Here is a working code snippet that will sort your array:

```
var array = ["5C", "4D", "2H", "13S", "4C", "5H"]

let sorted = array.sorted (by: { (first: String, second: String) -> Bool in
    return first.compare(second, options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending
})
```

The function `sorted()` is a "higher order function`, or a function that takes another function as a parameter. For an array of strings, that function takes 2 strings, and returns a Bool. It actually takes a closure rather than a function, where a closure is an "anonymous function" (a function with no name.)

Adapting vadian's code that gives the CORRECT answer to my snippet, it would look like this:

```
var array = ["5C", "4D", "2H", "13S", "4C", "5H"]

let sorted = array.sorted (by: { (first: String, second: String) -> Bool in
    if first.suffix(1) == second.suffix(1) {
        return first.dropLast.compare(second, options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending

    } else {
        return first.suffix(1) < second.suffix(1)
    }
})
```

You can rewrite the above with several shortcuts:

With a "trailing closure" you skip the `()` that contains the closure as a parameter and just provide the closure in braces after the function name.

You can skip the declaration of the parameters and return type of the closure, and skip the return statement:

```
let sorted = array.sorted { $0.compare($1, options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending }
```

For more complex code like vadian's that gives the correct answer, I suggest not using positional parameters like that. Using local variables like `first` and `second` make the code easier to read.

I suggest studying the chapter on Closures in Apple's Swift iBooks carefully until you understand the various ways that closures can be expressed and their different shortcut syntaxes. It's confusing at first, and using closures is fundamental to using Swift.

Comment: Just adding a shorthand version. Clean code is beautiful code. `let sorted = array.sorted { $0.compare($1, options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending } ` I think that's right.. no Code atm.

Comment: The result is `["2H", "4C", "4D", "5C", "5H", "13S"]` however this is not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: This is a great answer, and the best one if these strings have no higher-level meaning. However, given their structure and special treatment, I suspect they do. In that case, it's better out to parse out the values and give them nice names.

Comment: @vadian You are right, I did not look at the OPs desired results carefully enough. Your answer is correct for the OPs use-case (At least as long as the alpha suffix is always 1 letter, and it needs to be compared in Unicode order. (if the last character is always alpha, and it should be compared case-insensitive then your code will need a little fine-tuning, but your answer returns the desired result for the small data-set.)

Comment: The result is ["2H", "4C", "4D", "5C", "5H", "13S"]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. While the result wasn't what I was looking for, this still fills in the gap for a lot of questions I had. I'll check out the Swift iBooks. Thanks Duncan!

Comment: See the edit to my answer. I incorporated vadian's code, which gives the answer you wanted, into my answer. You should accept vadian's answer though. He was the first answer that gave the results you need.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

What do these numbers represent? I would create a `struct` to model that "thing" (I'll call it `Thing` for now), and function that can parse a `String` into a `Thing`, like so:

```
struct Thing: Equatable { // FIXME: Name me something descriptive
    let number: Int // FIXME: Name me something descriptive
    let letter: Character // FIXME: Name me something descriptive

    static func parse(from string: String) -> Thing? {
        let numberSegment = string.prefix(while: { $0.isNumber })
        guard !numberSegment.isEmpty,
            let number = Int(numberSegment) else { return nil }

        let letterSegement = string.drop(while: { $0.isNumber })
        guard letterSegement.count == 1,
            let letter = letterSegement.first else { return nil }

        return Thing(number: number, letter: letter)
    }
}
```

Then, you can just conform to `Comparable`, defining how you want things to be sorted, by defining the comparison operator `<`:

```
extension Thing: Comparable {
    static func < (lhs: Thing, rhs: Thing) -> Bool {
        return (lhs.letter, lhs.number) < (rhs.letter, rhs.number)
    }
}
```

From there, it's just a matter of parsing all your strings into `Thing`s, and sorting them:

```
let array = ["5C", "4D", "2H", "13S", "4C", "5H"]

let things = array.map { Thing.parse(from: $0)! }
print("Before sorting:")
things.forEach { print("\t\($0)") }

let sortedThings = things.sorted()
print("\nAfter sorting:")
sortedThings.forEach { print("\t\($0)") }
```

Output:

```
Before sorting:
    Thing(number: 5, letter: "C")
    Thing(number: 4, letter: "D")
    Thing(number: 2, letter: "H")
    Thing(number: 13, letter: "S")
    Thing(number: 4, letter: "C")
    Thing(number: 5, letter: "H")

After sorting:
    Thing(number: 4, letter: "C")
    Thing(number: 5, letter: "C")
    Thing(number: 4, letter: "D")
    Thing(number: 2, letter: "H")
    Thing(number: 5, letter: "H")
    Thing(number: 13, letter: "S")
```

Comment: This isn't the expected result either. The suffix is supposed to be sorted first then the prefix.

Comment: @vadian One line change, fixed :)

Comment: Wow Thank you for the thorough reply. So the numbers here represent a deck of cards where the letters represent suits and the numbers are ranks (11,12,13 are jack, queen, king respectively). I am attempting to construct a card game and sorting a hand. The 2-3 character codes represent the image names for a specific card so I can model it into the UI. I am a little confused on the function of struct so I will read more into that and perhaps my code will be a little more concise and practical. Thank you though this has given me some ideas on how to model my deck.

Comment: @Ehu9 Ah yes, I see the pattern now. Structs are a way of packaging related data and operations together. It's a one of the ways you can create your own data types in Swift. That way, you can say a function takes a `Card` (rather than just a generic `String`), so the Swift compiler can enforce that you can't give it nonsense like `"Hello World!"`. Yeah, you should make a `struct Card`, with `rank: Rank` and `suit: Suite`, where `Rank` and `Suite` are each enums which enumerate the 13 ranks (Ace, 2-10, J, Q, K), and 4 suites. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/24109691/3141234

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

this is my solution hope it works for you, I just organize first the numbers and next comparate with the alphabeth to create a new array:

```
var array = ["5C", "4D", "2H", "13S", "4C", "5H"]
    array = array.sorted { $0.numbersValues < $1.numbersValues }
    let str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    var newArrray: [String] = [] 
    for letter in str {
            for value in array {
                if value.lettersValues.hasPrefix(String(letter)) {
                       newArrray.append(value)
                }
            }
    }
```

Don't forget include this helpers methods in your project

```
    extension String {

        var lettersValues: String {
            return self.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits).joined()
        }

        var numbersValues: String {
            return self.filter { "0"..."9" ~= $0 }
        }
    }
```